# What's defining my font color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm not being able to change my tag's font color. I think this has something to do with specificity, but I can't make any advances to change it.

This is the code:

```
<header class="header" id="top">
  <div class="text-vertical-center">
    <h1>Reclamar não muda</h1>
    <h3>Free Bootstrap Themes &amp; Templates</h3>
    <br>
    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg js-scroll-trigger">Find Out More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Obviously, this code is nested inside `<html>`and `<body`> tags. These are the respective css for all the classes and id's that are showing up:

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/bg2) no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.text-vertical-center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
    font-size: 4.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.about {
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

When I try to change the color of the text `Reclamar não muda` (in portuguese, if you were wondering) , which is actually in some shade of grey, nothing happens. I try to input `font-color: white` or `font-color:#ffffff` in the `text-vertical-center` css code, but nothing happens.

This code is all from a free bootstrap code, by the way. If you need any more codes from it to be able to answer my question, please say so and I'll be happy to input them here.

Comment: try just `color` --  not `font-color`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in order to change a colour, you need the value **[`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)**, not `font-color`. It's also important to note that it **must** be written with the American spelling; `colour` won't work either.

You're looking for:

```
.text-vertical-center h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here's a working example (with a black background to demonstrate this):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.text-vertical-center {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.about {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="header" id="top">
  <div class="text-vertical-center">
    <h1>Reclamar não muda</h1>
    <h3>Free Bootstrap Themes &amp; Templates</h3>
    <br>
    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg js-scroll-trigger">Find Out More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the quick answer. I just changed `.text-vertical-center h1` as you recommended, but the font is still grey. Actually, the text even shrinked a lot :/

Comment: Correction: it worked when I put `color: #ffffff` on `.text-vertical-center`, but it is still very small. I tried to change `font-size` but I think this isn't helping

Comment: If you put it on `.text-vertical-center h1`, only the main title will change. If you put it on `.text-vertical-center`, both titles will change. If you want to change the `font-size` of the main title, the `font-size` declaration **must** be on `.text-vertical-center h1`, because it is already defined there, and that has higher specificity (alternatively, you could remove that declaration).

Comment: This is my actual code: 

.text-vertical-center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 4.5em;
}

This gives me a font that is not the initial one (I think it was source sans, but now it's helvetica, the second on the font-family line on `body`) and a really small h1 (sorry about the shitty formatting, kinda new to stackoverflow)

Comment: Modifying the `font-size: 4.5em` does indeed make your main title larger. Don't forget that you'll actually need to **include** your font on your page with `@font-face` in order to have it show up. And no worries about the formatting, though note that you can use the backtick ( ` ) to format code :)

Comment: Can you please tell me more about this `@font-face`?

Comment: No, for three reasons. The first being that StackOverflow is a question-answer site, not a chat room. The second, you did not initially ask about (nor even *mention*) a font-sizing problem; you asked about colour (which is what I answered). Third, asking about `font-size` is a completely different problem unrelated to the first one -- an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Second, asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources is considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has its own `h1` styles which might be overriding your style.  Also you are changing color incorrectly.  Try:

```
.text-vertical-center h1 {color:#ffffff}
```